# I'm creating a stats website for PUBG and I can't seem to get the total player count

Tags: api, steam

So at the moment I'm working on a PUBG stats website(I know it's been done a billion times but it's a fun project) but I can't seem to find the total player count in the official PUBG api. I know there is a way to get the player count but I've been going through steams and PUBG's official api and I can't find it. Anyone have an idea where to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not available through the game's API, or in any other game that I know.

There was a hole in the steam API a few months back that allowed that info to come through, but it has since been fixed. This is not the kind of data developers want you to have access to, really.

Give this article a read:

https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2018/07/steam-data-leak-reveals-precise-player-count-for-thousands-of-games/

Comment: Well I mean they are publicly releasing data for it every month and if u go to steams PUBG page u can see the players online. It's not like they are trying to hide it

Comment: Yes, you can get concurrent players thought's steam's API, that's how websites like steamcharts calculate the monthly average. Not total though. Try this one: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1